# ¿Como puedo redireccionar a otro componente desde una funcion de mi boton utilizando Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

estoy haciendo una app en next.js, pero quiero que el usuario cuando le de click a un boton en este caso el boton login, me redireccione a otro componente, este es una muestra de como esta el codigo de mi componente:

```
"use client"
import React from "react";
import "../styles/StylesContent.css";

const Content = () => {

function login() {

}

return (
    <div className="initial-content">
        
        <div className="container-photo">
            <button onClick={login}>Login</button>
        </div>

    </div>
);
};

export default Content;
```

como se puede observar la redireccion la quiero implementar en la funcion login donde se mandara al usuario al componente llamado Login.tsx, todos los componentes con los que estoy trabajando estan en una carpeta llamada components dentro del src